# EF core Does not insert all records for InMemoryDatabase

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Good day,

I am failing to insert multiple records in EF core using InMemory database. By failing I mean it works, but it seems that it does not insert all records.

This is my code to insert:

```
            var f1= new F1[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F1.AddRangeAsync(f1);

            var f2= new F2[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.f2.AddRangeAsync(f2);

            var f3= new F3[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F3.AddRangeAsync(f3);

            var f4= new F4[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F4.AddRangeAsync(f4);

            var f5= new F5[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F5.AddRangeAsync(f5);

            var f6= new F6[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F6.AddRangeAsync(f6);

            var f7= new F7[]{ /* Where I have populated this*/}
            await context.F7.AddRangeAsync(f7);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Where each collection has a minimum of 2 items and a maximum of 100.

After I run this code:

```
            var f1= await context.F1.ToListAsync();
            var f2= await context.F2.ToListAsync();
            var f3= await context.F3.ToListAsync();
            var f4= await context.F4.ToListAsync();
            var f5= await context.F5.ToListAsync();
            var f6= await context.F6.ToListAsync();
            var f7= await context.F7.ToListAsync();
```

And breakpoint after the f7 line and hover over the collections, I can see all of them have only part of the items.

This is how I create the in memory database:

```
services.AddDbContext<FamousDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyFamousDatabase"));
```

What I have tried so far:
1. I have tried to save (trigger SaveChanges) each time an item/collection is added.
2. Tried not using async to insert.
3. tried inserting only one collection and then only asking for on DbSet.
4. Tried researching documentation on EF core.
5. Tried changing the name of the in memory database.

My Assumption is that this is a limitation of InMemory Core, but I cannot confirm this without enough knowledge and not finding anything mentioned in documentation or anywhere else.

So my question is how do I get around this? Is this a limitation of using InMemory Db? Or am I doing something wrong on this one?

UPDATE:

I am using .NET core 2.2 and EF InMemory version: 2.2.4

UPDATE SOLVED:

I have managed to solve the problem, it seems it was for the reason EF core InMemory does not really support relational database, though I read it I did not think it was because of this until I went through try and error sessio, source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory. Because when I try to pre-populated the data each of the objects bellow "f1" has a reference to the F1 type in the following way:

```
public int F1Id {get;set}
public F1 F1 {get;set;}
```

As soon as I removed the object reference from all the objects and left only the F1Id it worked like a charm.

Comment: Did you try printing out the items? Maybe debugger is not showing all the items? Maybe try Count()-ing the items?

Comment: What version of .NET Core and EF Core are you using?

Comment: @Euphoric I have tried doing two different request to the database and checked the count in immediate window same thing.

Comment: Are the items not in DB same each run or different? Is there anything you can tell from items that are and aren't in DB?

Comment: They are the same each run. The database gets pre-populated with the same items each run. I tried changing the name of the InMemory database still same thing. @Euphoric